A small REPL in Python
The REPL offers functionality for inserting, deleting, and searching within a red-black tree, along with the capability to generate an ASCII or graphical representation of the tree structure.
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

from plot import plot_tree
from rbtree import RedBlackTree

COMMANDS = {
    "insert": lambda rbt, x: rbt.insert(x),
    "delete": lambda rbt, x: rbt.delete(x),
    "search": lambda rbt, x: print(rbt.search(x).get_key()),
    "print": lambda rbt: rbt.print_tree(),
    "plot": lambda rbt: plot_tree(rbt.get_root()),
    "exit": lambda rbt: exit(""),
}


def repl_loop() -> None:
    rbt = RedBlackTree()

    while True:
        try:
            line = input(">> ").rstrip()
        except EOFError:
            exit("")

        tokens = line.split()

        if not tokens:
            continue

        cmd = tokens[0]

        if cmd not in COMMANDS:
            print(f"Error: unknown command: {cmd}.")
            continue

        if cmd in {"print", "exit", "plot"}:
            if len(tokens) != 1:
                print("Error: extra argument.")
                continue
            COMMANDS[cmd](rbt)
            continue
        elif len(tokens) != 2:
            print("Error: expected 2 arguments.")
            continue
        COMMANDS[cmd](rbt, tokens[1])


def main() -> None:
    prompt = (
        "Welcome to RB-Tree REPL.\n"
        "Commands available: insert, delete, search, print, plot, exit.\n"
    )

    print(prompt)
    repl_loop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

The code has been formatted with black and isort.
Review Request:
Anything. Everything.

It doesn't make sense to pass a string to exit. That's supposed to be an integer returned to the operating system and accessible by a shell as the return code. If you want to indicate success, use 0 instead.
Don't use lambdas if you don't have to -

insert and delete can be non-bound references to RedBlackTree.insert and RedBlackTree.delete respectively
search should just be a function
print should be a non-bound reference to RedBlackTree.print_tree
plot should just be a function

Really, you don't need to do length checking at all. Just splat-pass your *tokens to the method, and if it throws, catch and print a message.
You should probably case-fold your command.
Don't hard-code your Commands available list; form that from a join() on your dictionary keys.

exit takes strings, but passing it a string is inappropriate here. If you pass it a string, it's treated as an error message. The exit code is 1 (indicating an error) and the string gets printed before exiting.

(Also exit is only supposed to be used in interactive mode, not in programs. Some Python execution settings don't actually have exit. You're supposed to use sys.exit instead.)

LGTM.
lambdas
Clearly the lambdas work, as-is.
Consider using def instead,
in a dedicated module so we can iterate over them.
This would open up new possibilities,
such as tacking on a number-of-args decorator.
Consider adding type annotations.
DRY
COMMANDS = {
    "insert": lambda rbt, x: rbt.insert(x),
    ...

def repl_loop() -> None:
        ...
        if cmd in {"print", "exit", "plot"}:
            if len(tokens) != 1:

This feels a bit redundant and hackish.
Consider putting num_args next to the function definition:
    "insert": (2, lambda rbt, x: rbt.insert(x)),

Consider using try to detect when a "call with wrong
number of args" failed,
so you can print an informative diagnostic.
Consider using the
inspect
module to learn how many args a lambda requires.

Re DRY: this should be a namedtuple, probably.

@SUTerliakov, Agreed, I am usually quite pleased to see namedtuple incorporated into someone’s design.
